# WSDL generation broken due to XmlElementRef

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I have to use this exact XSD, so no changes are possible. I could narrow down my problem to the following `localisationNameType`. 
When publishing the webservice without the `localisationNameType` all works fine and soapUI can generate a request. When adding the type it simply makes an empty project. Accessing by browser the wsdl can be opened. (It is no proxy-problem because I ran it on the localhost).

I also tried with soap 1.2 and 1.1 so that cause can be excluded as well. 
When trying to create a `Web Service Client`out of the Eclipse Wizard (Axis) I also get an error message which tells me:

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: Element {http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3}localisationDescriptionIndex is referenced but not defined.
```

When removing the `localisationDescriptionIndex` it simply takes the next field as invalid with the same error code/exception. As you can see the Element has an actual definition in the object factory but as the exception says it can't find it.

**What is wrong that I cannot generate a request with soapUI when publishing a soap-service with the following type?**

[Full XSD if needed](http://www.ech.ch/alfresco/guestDownload/attach/workspace/SpacesStore/c837927a-2527-4b42-bb50-08df7732de31/eCH-0129-3-0.xsd)

It concerns the following code:

```
<xs:complexType name="localisationNameType">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="localisationLanguage" type="eCH-0129:localisationLanguageType" />
        <xs:element name="localisationDescription" type="eCH-0129:longNameOfLocalisationType" />
        <xs:element name="localisationDescriptionShort" type="eCH-0129:shortNameOfLocalisationType"
            minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="localisationDescriptionIndex" type="eCH-0129:indexNameOfLocalisationType"
            minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:simpleType name="localisationLanguageType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:enumeration value="de" />
        <xs:enumeration value="fr" />
        <xs:enumeration value="it" />
        <xs:enumeration value="ro" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="longNameOfLocalisationType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:maxLength value="60" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="indexNameOfLocalisationType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:maxLength value="3" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="shortNameOfLocalisationType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:maxLength value="24" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

What Jaxb generates:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "localisationNameType", propOrder = {
    "localisationLanguageAndLocalisationDescriptionAndLocalisationDescriptionShort" })
public class LocalisationNameType {

@XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(
                name = "localisationDescriptionIndex", namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3",
                type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(
                name = "localisationLanguage", namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(
                name = "localisationDescription", namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(
                name = "localisationDescriptionShort", namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3",
                type = JAXBElement.class) })
protected List<JAXBElement<?>> localisationLanguageAndLocalisationDescriptionAndLocalisationDescriptionShort;
```

Object Factory:

```
/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 */
@XmlElementDecl(
        namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", name = "localisationDescription",
        scope = LocalisationNameType.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
public JAXBElement<String> createLocalisationNameTypeLocalisationDescription(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_LocalisationNameTypeLocalisationDescription_QNAME, String.class,
            LocalisationNameType.class, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 */
@XmlElementDecl(
        namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", name = "localisationDescriptionShort",
        scope = LocalisationNameType.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
public JAXBElement<String> createLocalisationNameTypeLocalisationDescriptionShort(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_LocalisationNameTypeLocalisationDescriptionShort_QNAME, String.class,
            LocalisationNameType.class, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LocalisationLanguageType }{@code >}}
 */
@XmlElementDecl(
        namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", name = "localisationLanguage", scope = LocalisationNameType.class)
public JAXBElement<LocalisationLanguageType> createLocalisationNameTypeLocalisationLanguage(
        LocalisationLanguageType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<LocalisationLanguageType>(_LocalisationNameTypeLocalisationLanguage_QNAME,
            LocalisationLanguageType.class, LocalisationNameType.class, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 */
@XmlElementDecl(
        namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", name = "localisationDescriptionIndex",
        scope = LocalisationNameType.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
public JAXBElement<String> createLocalisationNameTypeLocalisationDescriptionIndex(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_LocalisationNameTypeLocalisationDescriptionIndex_QNAME, String.class,
            LocalisationNameType.class, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LocalisationLanguageType }{@code >}}
 */
@XmlElementDecl(
        namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", name = "localityLanguage", scope = LocalityNameLongType.class)
public JAXBElement<LocalisationLanguageType> createLocalityNameLongTypeLocalityLanguage(
        LocalisationLanguageType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<LocalisationLanguageType>(_LocalityNameLongTypeLocalityLanguage_QNAME,
            LocalisationLanguageType.class, LocalityNameLongType.class, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 */
@XmlElementDecl(
        namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", name = "localityDescriptionLong",
        scope = LocalityNameLongType.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
public JAXBElement<String> createLocalityNameLongTypeLocalityDescriptionLong(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_LocalityNameLongTypeLocalityDescriptionLong_QNAME, String.class,
            LocalityNameLongType.class, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LocalisationLanguageType }{@code >}}
 */
@XmlElementDecl(
        namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", name = "localityLanguage", scope = LocalityNameShortType.class)
public JAXBElement<LocalisationLanguageType> createLocalityNameShortTypeLocalityLanguage(
        LocalisationLanguageType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<LocalisationLanguageType>(_LocalityNameLongTypeLocalityLanguage_QNAME,
            LocalisationLanguageType.class, LocalityNameShortType.class, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 */
@XmlElementDecl(
        namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0129/3", name = "localityDescriptionShort",
        scope = LocalityNameShortType.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
public JAXBElement<String> createLocalityNameShortTypeLocalityDescriptionShort(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_LocalityNameShortTypeLocalityDescriptionShort_QNAME, String.class,
            LocalityNameShortType.class, value);
}
```

How the Webservice is registered:

```
...
Endpoint.publish(soapService.getEndpoint(), soapService);
...
```

The service class:

```
@Service
@WebService(name = "SendService")
@BindingType(value = SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class SendServiceImpl implements SendService {
  ....
}
```